# TembooChoreo' was not declared in this scope

Tags: twitter, arduino, temboo

I am a new user for Temboo, I am trying to use their Choreo to interact with Arduino and Twitter. When I generate the code from Temboo and try to verify it in Arduino IDE I get these errors.

```
UserTimeline_Twitter.ino: In function 'void loop()':
UserTimeline_Twitter:52: error: 'TembooChoreo' was not declared in this scope
UserTimeline_Twitter:52: error: expected `;' before 'MentionsChoreo'
UserTimeline_Twitter:55: error: 'MentionsChoreo' was not declared in this scope
```

Can anyone please explain why I am getting this error? Thanks,

Below is the code example,

```
 #include <SPI.h>
#include <WiFi.h>
#include <WiFiClient.h>
#include <Temboo.h>
#include "TembooAccount.h" // Contains Temboo account information

WiFiClient client;

int numRuns = 1;   // Execution count, so this doesn't run forever
int maxRuns = 10;   // Maximum number of times the Choreo should be executed

void setup() {
  Serial.begin(9600);

  // For debugging, wait until the serial console is connected.
  delay(4000);
  while(!Serial);

  int wifiStatus = WL_IDLE_STATUS;

  // Determine if the WiFi Shield is present.
  Serial.print("\n\nShield:");
  if (WiFi.status() == WL_NO_SHIELD) {
    Serial.println("FAIL");

    // If there's no WiFi shield, stop here.
    while(true);
  }

  Serial.println("OK");

  // Try to connect to the local WiFi network.
  while(wifiStatus != WL_CONNECTED) {
    Serial.print("WiFi:");
    wifiStatus = WiFi.begin(WIFI_SSID, WPA_PASSWORD);

    if (wifiStatus == WL_CONNECTED) {
      Serial.println("OK");
    } else {
      Serial.println("FAIL");
    }
    delay(5000);
  }

  Serial.println("Setup complete.\n");
}

void loop() {
  if (numRuns <= maxRuns) {
    Serial.println("Running Mentions - Run #" + String(numRuns++));

    TembooChoreo MentionsChoreo(client);

    // Invoke the Temboo client
    MentionsChoreo.begin();

    // Set Temboo account credentials
    MentionsChoreo.setAccountName(TEMBOO_ACCOUNT);
    MentionsChoreo.setAppKeyName(TEMBOO_APP_KEY_NAME);
    MentionsChoreo.setAppKey(TEMBOO_APP_KEY);

    // Set profile to use for execution
    MentionsChoreo.setProfile("TwitterAccount");

    // Set Choreo inputs
    String CountValue = "5";
    MentionsChoreo.addInput("Count", CountValue);

    // Identify the Choreo to run
    MentionsChoreo.setChoreo("/Library/Twitter/Timelines/Mentions");

    // Run the Choreo; when results are available, print them to serial
    MentionsChoreo.run();

    while(MentionsChoreo.available()) {
      char c = MentionsChoreo.read();
      Serial.print(c);
    }
    MentionsChoreo.close();
  }

  Serial.println("\nWaiting...\n");
  delay(30000); // wait 30 seconds between Mentions calls
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It looks you you don't have Temboo's Arduino library installed. Older versions of the Arduino IDE (1.0.x) don't come with the Temboo library by default, so I'd recommend upgrading to the latest 1.5.x version. You can download the Arduino software here:

http://arduino.cc/en/main/software#toc3